# Firestore with Bigquery or Tensorflow for training and predictions?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I am using Google-Firestore as data storage for my mobile application. I want to Pub/Sub `onChange` or export data every day to train a custom AI model. The model would make predictions based on which I can nudge the user on the app.

What is the best Google Cloud Platform architecture for something like this? I thought Bigquery or Tensorflow might work, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Please tell something about the AI model. Tensorflow is (usually) for neural networks. So it depends a lot on the kind of calculation you want to run on all data.

Comment: I have time series data of user activities. I want to build a prediction model

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are trying to achieve. Try and keep it as simple as possible otherwise, you will create a problematic model that is hard to debug if it goes wrong. I would take a look at the Firebase Machine Learning mobile SDK. I have added some of the documentation below for you to see if it meets your requirements.

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml)

> Firebase Machine Learning is a mobile SDK that brings Google's machine learning expertise to Android and iOS apps in a powerful yet easy-to-use package. Whether you're new or experienced in machine learning, you can implement the functionality you need in just a few lines of code. There's no need to have in-depth knowledge of neural networks or model optimization to get started. On the other hand, if you are an experienced ML developer, Firebase ML provides convenient APIs that help you use your custom TensorFlow Lite models in your mobile apps.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit)

> ML Kit brings Google's machine learning expertise to mobile developers in a powerful and easy-to-use package. Make your iOS and Android apps more engaging, personalized, and helpful with optimised solutions to run on the device.

Comment: I have my data on the cloud. I need my model to be on the cloud, not the device.

Comment: @SrinivasA Did you find the answer?